# CMake use -openmp instead of -qopenmp for Intel Compiler

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, openmp, icc

I'm building OpenCV on a Xeon Phi using the Intel Compiler v16. These are the cmake settings:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo -DWITH_TBB=OFF -DWITH_OPENMP=ON -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=icc -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=icpc ..
```

However, using `-DWITH_OPENMP=ON` produces the flag `-openmp` which is depecrated, instead it should use `-qopenmp`. How can I tell to cmake to use the correct flag?

Comment: What's your CMake version? Have you tried the latest one like 3.7.2 or 3.8-rc1?

Comment: Oh thanks for the tip! I'll check ASAP !

Comment: Seems that this was fixed in [CMake 3.1.0](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/commit/4671f3ab7dc65186484ce31dff5e810aa2792145) -- you're probably seriously out of date. Either way, you have the source code for [OpenCV](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/cmake/OpenCVFindLibsPerf.cmake#L139) that you can patch, as well as the Find* scripts from CMake. Use the source! :)

Comment: That was the problem! If you're going to post it as an answer I'm going to choose it ;)